# How can I add form feed character into text that I am creating with XSLT?

Tags: xml

I need to generate text output using xml pulbisher with xls-text type.  I got stuck with inserting "form feed" character as part of the text outputl.  can someone help?

The text output is used to feed another check printer and will need "form feed" character as page break for new page.  XML doesn't like ascii code and {FF} doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Stacey

Comment: Show what you've tried that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The Form feed control character is not a legal character in XML 1.0. It's available in XML 1.1, so you will need to find an XSLT processor that supports XML 1.1. Saxon does - if you set the appropriate options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting formfeed character then you should be generating text output, not XML.  I found this method worked for me:

```
`<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY FF "<![CDATA[&#12;]]>">`
`<xsl:stylesheet ...
    :
    :
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    :
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&FF;</xsl:text>
    :
```

`