# How to add Page Break in XSL-Text XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, bi-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I am creating a Text output from Oracle XML Publisher. I am using XSLT 1.0. There is a requirement to add Page Break after every 62 lines during output generation.

I am not sure how Page Break is added in XSLT file.

Can someone help?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Possible dupe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034302/how-can-i-add-form-feed-character-into-text-that-i-am-creating-with-xslt

Comment: It depends to some extent on what a page break *is* for your purposes.  In any case, it would probably be easier to postprocess the output of your transform, perhaps by piping it through a pagination script.  Or perhaps XML Publisher has a built-in feature that you are expected to use.

Comment: Thanks John. I am doing a postprocess after output is generated. I am using awk to get desired page break